# Постоянно вылезает ошибки нехватки памяти в opencart

Tags: opencart3.x

Захожу в редактирование прав группы пользователей выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /home/site.com/public_html/admin/controller/user/user_permission.php on line 331
```

Но проблема в том что ставлю 256М выдает такую ошибку, ставлю 1024М(по факту ВМ там 4гб) то он бесконечно крутит, помогите решить проблему

код ошибки

```
    // While the path array is still populated keep looping through
    while (count($path) != 0) {
        $next = array_shift($path);

        foreach (glob($next) as $file) {
            // If directory add to path array
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                $path[] = $file . '/*';
            }

            // Add the file to the files to be deleted array
            if (is_file($file)) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: предположу, что и бд крутится на том же хосте и кушает немало памяти

Comment: @DmitryKozlov все остальное работает быстро, сайт вообще поставили новый

Comment: посмотрите в `user_permission.php on line 331` может там рекурсия, которая генерирует список, пока не упадет по памяти

Comment: или настроен/ненастроен какой-то параметр, который не дает выйти из бесконечного цикла

Comment: @DmitryKozlov вот добавил

Comment: Попробуйте удалить пустые папки в `/admin/controller/`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov там нету пустых папок

Comment: А нет ли в каталоге продукта символических ссылок на вышестоящие папки? Такое впечатление, что перебор дерева каталогов зацикливается

Comment: @DmitryKozlov как это сделать? если честно вообще не понял, в папке каталог? или в каталоге товаров?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov в логах есть ошибки на модификатор
2022-09-26 12:32:30 - PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/site.com/public_html/system/modification.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/site.com/public_html/admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php on line 114

Comment: В папке `controller` приложения. Из кода, это `DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/*'`